# Force users to use password with specifications

Tags: users, security, password

I want my users to follow a selection of rules when they create their password.

The users don't have the possibility to create a account. I make it for them. 
However I found that users regularly loose their passwords. So they click the "forgot password" link.

When creating a new password I want them to follow a set of rules.
For instance:
- min. 6 and max. 12 characters.
- 1 uppercase letter
- 1 lowercase letter
- 1 number
- 1 special character

I have no idea how to accomplish this. Tried Googling for a plugin but no luck.

Can anybody assist me with this? Like a plugin or something?
A paid plugin is not a problem.

M.

Comment: May I ask why? These rules lead to weak passwords, because they are encouraging users to reuse passwords. Also 12 characters is way too short. WordPress has no such limitation. Any system with a max length is broken by design.

Comment: Interesting. How do they encourage to reuse? I thought these rules would force the user to have a versatile password

Comment: Passwords with such rules are hard to remember (and easy to crack), so most users will just switch between two passwords they can remember. One every web site. Encourage long pass phrases without upper restrictions is you are out for security.

Comment: Okay so basically you are telling me to keep the password creator that WordPress provides. Then I might want to look for something that won't allow the password to be saved if the status doesn't reach "strong".

Comment: Yes, that would probably be the best.The technical problem here is that the visible "weakness" indicator is written in Javascript, and there is no exact equivalent in PHP for that.

Comment: Why would know-it-alls down-vote these Qs? It is a valid request. Low-level accounts do not always need 12 character passwords - responders to these Qs should not assume the purpose or the requirement - just answer the Q.

Answer (score 1):

You can use anyone plugin from below:

1) [Strong Password Generator](https://wordpress.org/plugins/strong-password-generator/)

2) [Force Strong Passwords](https://wordpress.org/plugins/force-strong-passwords/)

3) [Minimum Password Strength](https://wordpress.org/plugins/minimum-password-strength/)

Hope this will helps you.

Comment: Thnx. I have seen all of them already but don;t do what I want. What I want is not uncommon to various websites. I mean I see this a lot.